# gulpfile.js - task is not in gulp file error

Tags: javascript, gulp

Below is my current `Gulpfile.js` and when I'm attempting to run `gulp minify` I'm getting the error, **"Task 'minify' is not in your gulpfile"**. However, I'm able to run `gulp sass` with no issues. I also have each module installed with npm.

```
module.exports = function(gulp) {
'use strict'

var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('minify', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/min'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'cssnano'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);

});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
        baseDir: 'app/'
        },
    })
})
}
```

Comment: Gulpfiles are not wrapped in a function like gruntfiles.

Answer (score 0):

You should not treat the `gulpfile.js` as a node module and drop the following part

```
module.exports = function(gulp) {
```

(don't forget to remove the closing curly (`}`) at the end of the `gulpfile.js`)

Then, you should require gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

That should make it run smoothly.

---

Why it does run your `gulp sass`, I don't know. I just created a simple test file in a fresh directory, and it didn't recognise the `sass` task for me. Maybe you installed`gulp`, `sass` or both globally at some point (e.g. earlier project).

Comment: Great point Rogier. I think that is the likely reason, but, if I have `gulp`, `sass`, and all of the other node modules installed as a dev dependency, why am I seeing this error?

Comment: It most likely is a search path issue, on OSX/Linux you can enter a command `which gulp` in your terminal, that would give the location of the `gulp` executable you are actually running (if this is not `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` you aren't using the project install of `gulp`). You can then try to provide the correct path yourself by running `./node_modules/.bin/gulp minify`.
The part I don't fully understand is which `gulpfile.js` is found by `gulp`, clearly it has to be one which registers a `sass` task successfully, though `gulp` AFAIK only looks in the current directory for a `gulpfile.js`.